# Is there a better solution for caching than MD5 Fingerprinting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, md5, browser-cache, cdn

I understand the easyness of comparing the automatically generated MD5 fingerprint in order to determine if a file has or hasn't been changed.

My question is: **is MD5 Fingerprint the only approach to caching?**

I supposed not, I know I've been able to cache both in the Client and in the Server without using MD5 fingerprinting.

So, depending on the answer: **Why would I use MD5 fingerprint if I can achieve the same thing without using it?** Why add complexity?

*Why am I asking that?*

I'm using Gulp as a replacement for the Rails Asset Pipeline and having a hard time to make Rails use the newly generated manifest.json.

The workflow is perfect (gulp-unccs, gulp-livereload, gulp-jshint and whatnot) and I love it (much faster) but I'm not sure as to why (if?) I need to do the MD5 Fingerprinting.

Comment: If not a hash function, how else would you do it?

Comment: That is precisely my question :) Is it the only way for a Browser to tell if a file has changed? Does the expire headers work regardless of it?

Comment: The hard part with caching is _invalidation_. Suppose, your cache is set to expire in 1 year. Browser caches the file and two days later you change it. Too bad, the client won't see the change for ~360 days. That's some lousy cache here.

Comment: I don't know how a reliable efficient cache invalidation can be implemented without some kind of content-based fingerprinting.

Comment: Sure you can use whatever, but you need a unique string.

Comment: I understand the issue of invalidation, makes perfect sense. What I can't tell is if there's any other way around it...

Comment: @JonathanSoifer: why is this even a problem? Rails handles it for you. You don't have to do literally anything.

Comment: I'm replacing the Rails Asset Pipeline using Gulp. This is the practical reason behind it: so I'm using gulp-rev (actually gulp-rev-all) to generate the MD5 hashing and I'm trying to understand how this process works.
But this is actually more of a conceptual question: not so hard really: Is there another way to do it or not?

Comment: @JonathanSoifer: as I said, I'm not aware of another approach that is both reliable (invalidates when needed) and efficient (doesn't invalidate when not needed). Someone else might know.

Comment: @JonathanSoifer: put your rationale into the question. Should prevent some downvotes. :)

Comment: Good, I'm updating it :)